# Traveling to Serbia

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, serbia

I am an Indian traveling to Serbia from 22nd to 26th of this month with my family , having booked a travel plan through Holiday Factory in Dubai.

Please can someone advice what are the documents to be provided at the Serbian Immigration for getting visa on arrival. Is there a chance of refusal? how much money should I carry for a family of 3 for a trip of 4 days. Is there a mandatory amount to be carried if my hotel booking is confirmed?  Please can someone advice which are the must see tourist spots and which is the best way to travel to these spots . Any precautions to be taken?

Comment: According to this website http://www.mfa.gov.rs/en/consular-affairs/entry-serbia/entering-serbia-requirements, in addition to a valid passport, proof of sufficient funds of €50 per day is required, and travel insurance is recommended. The actual amount you’ll need depends on what you plan to do during your trip.

Answer (score 2):

In the Fall of 2017, Serbia began visa free entry for Indians holding ordinary passports. Nationals of the Republic of India can enter, transit through and stay in the Republic of Serbia without a visa, during a period not exceeding 30 days from the date of entry.

For a family of three, you would want to show sufficient funds (50 Euros per day per person, $150 for a total of €660). This could be in cash, credit card, or traveller's cheques.

Carry with you proof health insurance for the period in Serbia, covering possible medical costs to the amount of not less than 20,000 Euros.

As for what to see and do, a quick Google search on 'Serbia tourist attractions' returns many offerings, such as the [Serbia.com](http://www.serbia.com/visit-serbia/cities/belgrade/top-attractions/) top attractions list. The same site has an article on [things to know before travelling to Serbia](http://www.serbia.com/10-things-know-traveling-serbia/).